# How to get forward iterator that starts from the last element

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

I have a `LinkedList`. Suppose that I'm inserting an element at the end and I want to save the position where was it inserted, so that I can call a function on an element next to it, whatever manages to get into this collection later. Is it possible with Java iterators? Many thanks.

Just to recollect, I'm not interested in reverse iteration. The application will be multithreaded, hence the weird requirement.

Comment: What about `list.offerFirst(list.removeLast())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `List#listIterator(int index)` with index = `size() -1` to get an iterator to the current last element of the list. See documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html

However, you are going to be stuck from there.

Whether the List implementation you are using isn't thread-safe, which is the case for LinkedList, ArrayList and most others, and any attempt to use the iterator after the list has been structurally modified is going to result in a ConcurrentModificationException being thrown.
A list is structurally modified when its size changes, i.e. on additions and removals.

Or the List implementation you are using is thread-safe, in which case you have no guaranty that the iterator will have access to the elements added to the list after the creation of the iterator.
For example, it wouldn't be the case with CopyOnWriteArrayList, for which the iterator iterates through data as it was at creation (like a snapshot).

You must find an implementation of List that clearly describe this behavior and explicitly say it in its documentation. As far as I know, there doesn't exist any that allow it, at least in the standard library.